# Connecting sequel pro to docker mysql

Tags: mysql, docker, sequelpro

I have followed a guid on how to install mysql to docker [here](https://database.guide/how-to-install-sql-server-on-a-mac/).
On running the `docker ps` I get:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                        COMMAND                  CREATED             
3e477bb5aaf9.       mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest   "/opt/mssql/bin/perm…"   53 seconds ago

STATUS                   PORTS                                   NAMES                                
Up 52 seconds            0.0.0.0:1433->1433/tcp                  sql_server
```

I have tried to connect to it from sequel pro like this:

[image]

But, that didn't work. I got the connection error message:

```
Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1, or the request timed out.

Be sure that the address is correct and that you have the necessary privileges, or try increasing the connection timeout (currently 10 seconds).

MySQL said: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (4)
```

I wonder how can I get connected with Sequel Pro to mysql server on docker?

Comment: What do you mean "That didnt work"? Did your computer explode? Did it throw an error? Did the screen freeze?

Comment: It threw connection error message. I have added it to the question.

Comment: Your container is SQL Server. Download Azure Data Studio and try to connect to your container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've messed up between MySQL and MSSQL. These two are completely different products with incompatible protocols. `sequelpro`  is the tool to connect to MySQL server, while you are running MSSQL. No magic, it can't connect.